# Role base access control system for admin and super_admin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get this result -> Use access control logic for two user types: administrators and super administrators.

Administrators will have read access to all records within the system however they will have edit/delete access to only those records that are created by them.

Super administrators will have read/edit/delete access to all records. In this case what should i use? if any one know how to give Roll back accessing control in simple manner in above case then please tell me how to do this?

after login from admin_login.php my page comes here...
this is my controller page..

listing.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Listing extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('student');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $s = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
    log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
}
public function index()
{
    $s = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');

    $this->load->model('student',$s);
   //$data['result'] = $this->student->listing();
    $students = $this->student->listing();/////new line delete [resulet]time 5:42 29/03/16
     //$this->load->view('list_view',$data); //// change here time 5:52 29/03/16
    $this->load->view('list_view',array('students'=>$students)); /////listing->list_view name change
}   
public function delete($id)
{

    $result = $this->student->delete_operation($id);
    $s = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');// session data call.
    //$data['result'] = $this->student->listing();
    $students = $this->student->listing();///new line 30/03 1230pm// change for list_view
    $this->load->view('list_view',array('students'=>$students));///same as above//change for list_view
    //$this->load->view('list_view',$data); ////////////////////////listing->list_view name change
} 

public function edit($id)
{               


    if($id)
    {
        $s = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
        $result = $this->student->edit_record($id);   
        $data['action'] = 'edit';
        $data['student_id'] = $result[0]->student_id;
        $data['student_name'] = $result[0]->student_name;
        $data['student_email'] = $result[0]->student_email;
        $data['student_address'] = $result[0]->student_address;
        $data['subject'] = $result[0]->subject;
        $data['marks'] = $result[0]->marks;

    }

    $this->load->view('edit_student',$data);   
}   
public function add_student()
{       
    //$s['user'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');//get session data // new line30/03/16
    $data['student_id'] = '';
    $data['student_name'] = '';
    $data['student_email'] = '';
    $data['student_address'] ='';
    $data['subject'] = '';
    $data['marks'] = '';
    //$data['admin_id']=''; //new line 12:39 30/03/16
    $this->load->view('edit_student',$data);           
}

public function add()
{
    $data = array(
    'student_name' => $this->input->post('txt_name'),
    'student_email' => $this->input->post('txt_email'),          
    'student_address' => $this->input->post('txt_address'),
    'subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),
    'marks' => $this->input->post('marks'),
    'admin_id' => $this->input->post('admin_id')//new line 12:39 31/03
    );
    $result = $this->student->add_record($id,$data);
    header('location:'.base_url().'index.php/listing');
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to use some roles in your system, for instance you can use the Ion auth library:
http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

With this you can define user groups (e.g.: user,administrator,superadministrator)
you can check the in_group() part of the manual to see how it works.
An example function to let you get some idea how can you check the record deleting:

```
function hasDeleteRight($record_author_id, $logged_in_user_id) {
    // if the user has administrator role we check if he is the author of the record he can delete it
    if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('administrator', $logged_in_user_id)) {
        if($record_author_id == $logged_in_user_id) {
            return true;
        }
    // if the user has superadministrator role he anyway can delete the record
    } elseif ($this->ion_auth->in_group('superadministrator', $logged_in_user_id)) {
        return true;
    }
    // other users cannot delete the record
    return false;
}
```

You still can use this example as base of functions.

usage in your code:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $logged_user_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
    if(!hasDeleteRight($id, $logged_user_id))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //....your delete record code
```

**update:**
permission check without ion auth, only with session data and separated login (not preferred way):
in the super admin login code you can put the permission into session:

```
function super_admin_login() {
    //your log in code
    if($login_success) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('permission', 'superadministrator');
    }
}
```

similar for normal administrator login:

```
function admin_login() {
    //your log in code
    if($login_success) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('permission', 'administrator');
    }
}


function hasDeleteRight($record_author_id, $logged_in_user_id) {
    // if the user has administrator role we check if he is the author of the record he can delete it
    if ($this->session->userdata('permission') == 'administrator') {
        if($record_author_id == $logged_in_user_id) {
            return true;
        }
    // if the user has superadministrator role he anyway can delete the record
    } elseif ($this->session->userdata('permission') == 'superadministrator') {
        return true;
    }
    // other users cannot delete the record
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hello @zaragoli can we done this without any auth library?

Comment: Yes, if you can make difference between admin users based on their 'admin_id'. How do you store what user have 'superadministrator' permission? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I don't think the best practise to create several logins for every user type, I still suggest you use the ion auth library where you can easily define roles. But if you don't want that (for some reason) check my updated example.

Comment: hello, when i am going to load ion_auth library it give me errer message that is-- Unable to load the requested class: Ion_auth